# change font type (editor font) Rstudio version 1.2 and Window 10 OS

Tags: r, rstudio

I would like to have more options regarding font style (Editor Font) on Rstudio. Currently I only have font styles like Consolas, Lucida, MS Gothic. I know my system has Arial installed but I can't view Arial on Rstudio option dropdown menu as per the following image:

[image]

Is there any way to have more options of my system font styles on Rstudio ?

A glimpse of my installed fonts on the following image.

[image]

Comment: The assumption is that for writing code, you'd want a monospaced font, which Arial is not

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change fonts by downloading .ttf file and installing (right click install) it. After restarting RStudio it should appear in the list.